# Cannot find a way to make a joined query result encodable in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I want to display the result of a `join` query (which debug shows is working) in a leaf template:

```
persons.get("/persons")
{ request ->Future<View> in
    return Title.query(on:request).join(\Person.titleId, to:\Title.id)
                .alsoDecode(Person.self).all().flatMap(to: View.self)  { pers in
        let context = APContext(title: "Demo", personnel: pers)
        let leaf = try request.make(LeafRenderer.self)
        return leaf.render("persons", context)
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find a way of passing the context directly as an array (like in Vapor 2). So, I am trying to use the codable structure:

```
struct APContext: Encodable {
    let title: String
    let personnel: [(Title,Person)]
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/leaf/basics/) is out-of-date as it suggests creating the `personnel` property as `EncodableStream` will work, but this has been removed. If the `struct` above is used it gives a compilation error:

> Type 'APContext' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

If I simplify the query so the the definition becomes:

```
let personnel = [Person]
```

Then it works.

So, I suppose my question boils down to: how do I make `[(Title,Person)]` encodable?

Comment: make a `struct Personnel` with two properties instead of a tuple

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus. I used your suggestion - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Leo's suggestion, I have got a solution:

```
struct Personnel: Encodable {
    let title: Title
    let person: Person
}
```

And include the following in the route:

```
var enc: [Personnel] = []
for per in pers {
    enc.append(Personnel(title:per.1,person:per.0))
}
```

`enc` can now be passed to the leaf template happily. The only thing to watch for is that the tags must include the field name from the `personnel` structure, e.g. `per.person.surname`.